# Where can I get more training on Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am brand new to Cocos2d and have begun making a simple card game.  I've followed the simple 3 part tutorial on the main Cocos2d-iphone website, but it did not cover everything I need.  While it covered a large amount of information, there are still many things that are left out.  For example, I had to view other project's source code in order to know that I must create an NSMutableArray of images for the cards, then make 2 sided objects (for front and back), then use a very special "shuffle" program.  While that's great and all, I'm stuck for the next phase of the game, which is:

- Dealing to players around the table
  *Face down for all 3 AI players, but face up for the main player
  *Dealt in specific pattern, fanned out like you were holding them in your hand

I've viewed several OLD (3 years) projects that are available online, but they were only slightly helpful.  Some of the projects have a HUD layer, while others don't.  Some projects don't even use the Cocos2d framework, but some do.

Anyway, I'm really eager to push on and keep working but my knowledge level is just not where it needs to be in order to proceed.  If anyone could offer some guidance, I would deeply appreciate it.  Sitting on my hands and googling night after night is driving me crazy.

Comment: You could get my book Learn cocos2d 2 which is hot off the press, and the first to cover cocos2d 2.0 and ARC. More info: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/

Comment: Having worked through 75%ish of Learn cocos2d 2 book I can highly recommend it! I believe its the best resource to start your Cocos2d career with at the moment. Then once you have read that I would re read the tutorials on Ray Wenderlich website (link given in answer below) then once you feel more comfortable I would recommend http://cocos2dbook.com written by Ray Wenderlich and Rod Strougo, though its based on an older version of Cocos2d and thus some of the code is now outdated, it does cover how to implement a full game so will give a good understanding of one method of game design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing beats youtube. type in `cocos2d tutorials`  and maybe learn something new!

Comment: Thanks. This is actually something I have not tried yet.  I thought there might be a more structured solution (like the book suggested above ), but free.  I'll try this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Cocos2d, or want to start cocos2d game development..

try some of the tutorial by [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials). He has some good tutorials for beginners and intermediates.

Comment: Excellent advice for anyone. Unfortunately, I am already reading his tutorials regularly.

Comment: I also found a great resource here:  [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent website with an excellent book.  I used it to teach myself Cocos2D.

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com